# How to point Epiphany to a new URL when it was launched in application mode?

Tags: gnome, dbus, epiphany

GNOME's default browser, Epiphany has a a handy feature that lets you turn any website into what acts like an independent application.  In reality all it does is create a `.desktop` in `${HOME}/.local/share/applications/` that launches Epiphany with the `--application-mode` flag.  Here's an example of one I setup for [Linear](https://linear.app/):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=epiphany --application-mode --profile=/home/daniel/.local/share/org.gnome.Epiphany.WebApp_af502f2b37eea07ed9083c7daf40f34553f6fccd https://linear.app/companyname/team/AAA/active
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;
StartupWMClass=org.gnome.Epiphany.WebApp_af502f2b37eea07ed9083c7daf40f34553f6fccd
X-Purism-FormFactor=Workstation;Mobile;
Name=Linear
Icon=/home/daniel/.local/share/applications/linear.png
```

This is handy for people like me who like to split their development process over multiple workspaces and don't want to have to flip back to Firefox and find a tab in a haystack of tabs every time you want to check a ticket.

I'm now fiddling with an idea where I could click on a URL in Slack or Thunderbird and have it open in the appropriate "app": work tickets for Jira/Linear/whatever, Git(Hub|Lab) to the appropriate app as well, etc.

The trouble I'm having at the moment though is that while I can *launch* Epiphany to point to any URL I want using whatever profile I want, I can't figure out how to point one of these pseudo apps to a new URL when it's currently running.

For example this will open the Linear app to the specified URL:

```bash
$ epiphany --application-mode --profile=/home/daniel/.local/share/org.gnome.Epiphany.WebApp_af502f2b37eea07ed9083c7daf40f34553f6fccd https://linear.app/companyname/issue/AAA-111/the-name-of-the-ticket
```

However if you run that command *when the Linear app is already open*, running the above does nothing.

I can run the above command *without* `--application-mode`, but that just opens the URL in a new browser window, and if I run that *again*, it just opens yet another browser window :-(

I'm hoping that there's some API available to let me say "hey browser window that's already open, go here: https://...".  If I can't do this via the command line, maybe dbus can do it?  I have no idea, but I'm hoping the SO community does.  Worst case scenario I suppose I could find and kill any running instance of the app in question and re-launch it, but that's obviously not ideal.